# How to compile two plots in knitr with echo=FALSE?

Tags: r, plot, knitr

When I compile the following *within* the same code chunk in to PDF:

````
```{r, fig.height= 5, fig.width=5, echo=FALSE}
par(mfcol=(1,1))
plot(rnorm(100))
plot(rnorm(100))
```
````

I get two plots right next two each other. Even though I specified one plot only. 
So far the only solution I have found is to separate them in to different code chunks, but I wonder if there is a cleaner fix. 
Thanks,

Comment: Have you tried replacing `par(mfcol=c(1,1))` with `par(mfrow=c(2,1))`?

Comment: It that case it will give me a smaller plot where the total length and width will be 5. I'm looking for two plots of that size.

Comment: Then why not setting `fig.height=10` and `par(mfrow=c(2,1))`?

Comment: That sounds like a good work around. The problem is that I want to to this for multiple sets of plots, where the number of plot varies.

Comment: Could you make the number of rows variable (e.g. `par(mfrow=c(numplots, 1))`)

Comment: Sam, while this would make the plots appear in a vertical column, they would appear as one figure.  This would require the `fig.height` option to be adjusted in the chunk options.  This then creates the problem that, as one figure, if the figure is too tall to fit on the page, it will just run off the page instead of rendering on the next page.  The crux of the issue is that this isn't anything to do with R and everything to do with LaTeX, and so it needs a LaTeX solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an ugly hack, and I'm sure there's a better way to get what you want, but this should do what you need:

````
```{r, fig.height= 5, fig.width=5, echo=FALSE, results='asis'}
plot(rnorm(100))
cat("\\newline")
plot(rnorm(100))
```
````

Though, this might be slightly less offensive

````
```{r, fig.height= 5, fig.width=5, echo=FALSE}
plot(rnorm(100))
knitr::asis_output("\\newline")
plot(rnorm(100))
```
````

Comment: You're correct, RHertel.  That was a sloppy copy/paste job, and I've edited the answer for cleanliness.

Comment: This just gives me a LaTeX error that it doesn't know the command \\newline however. knitr::asis_output("\\") did work.